# Row number in function changes when I delete rows in datasheet

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Everytime I delete rows in my "Formdata" sheet, then the following function changes. How can i stop that?

This part:

```
Formdata!$A$2:E
```

This function:

```
={Formdata!A1:E1;sortn(sort(Formdata!$A$2:E,1,false),9^9,2,2,true)}
```

Changes to:

```
={Formdata!A1:E1;sortn(sort(Formdata!$A$3:E,1,false),9^9,2,2,true)}
```

Seems i'm not able to fix the function to always use cell A2. When i delete rows in the "source sheet", then it increment the value and break the function.

Hope one of you might be able to help me here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to lock it down as string reference:

```
={Formdata!A1:E1; SORTN(SORT(INDIRECT("Formdata!A2:E"), 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)}
```